# Finding Correlation between Defect Rate and Handling Time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, trend, poisson-binomial-distribution

My team works to resolve online tasks assigned to them through a queue system; time taken to clear each task is measured (called handle_seconds). Approximately 18% of the tasks turn out to be defective. I want to check if there is a relationship between time taken to complete the task (handle_seconds) and the chance that output is defective.

One option I considered is bucketing the number of tasks and defects based on time window of, say every minute of handle_seconds and see the trend of share of defects in each window. But the handle_seconds range from 16 seconds to sometime a few hours, so the range is very large.

I wanted to know if there is a more accurate and established way of solving this, such as a statistical test.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple application of binomial logistic regression.

The outcome would be a 0/1 binary variable for no-defect/defect. The main predictor variable of interest would be `handle_seconds`, treated as a continuous variable. The wide range of that predictor can be addressed by working with its logarithm and by using a flexible model of its association with outcome, for example via regression splines. Breaking it up into bins is [not a good idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500).

If there are other aspects of the tasks that might be associated with outcome, those can also be incorporated into the logistic regression.

This [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) has links to how to implement logistic regression with several software packages.